# How to interface with app "MobilePASS+" (of Thales company) in Flutter?

Tags: two-factor-authentication

I have created login UI but I need to let user input two-factor and now I have registered in app MobilePASS+. Which I don't know how to link OTP user inputted with MobilePASS+ matched or not in Flutter code.

I need to write logic in Flutter that if user copy OTP from app "MobilePASS+", how I check matching OTP number.